Watery brown suger syrup fermented into what?
I made brown suger syrup with coconut suger a while back... it got too thick so I added water and the leftovers stayed in a plastic bottle. Over time I noticed the bottle had built up pressure, and went through a series of smells, which now smells like something quite pleasant, and fermented like. I even noticed bubbles this time. It's kept up building pressure and I've kept releasing it. Solids collect on the bottom and I keep skaking them back in. I want to taste it or see what I could use it for, but I'm nervous, lol, and I have no idea what it may have made. Any ideas what might have happened and what it now is? And is it safe for consumption or baking?

Depending on the result -- which you're going to need to taste to find out -- you've likely made either a kind or arak, or more likely coconut vinegar.  Either would be quite edible, but not a substitute for the original sugar syrup.
